# generate pdf from php fetching data from database in the form of table and send it to the user by email

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I want to fetch data from db in the form of table and generate pdf or excel of that data and want to send it to the user by email directly using php and sql.

Someone please help to solve me this problem.
I dont want anyone to write code for me but give me some suggestions to solve it.

```
      <?php
session_start();
include ('db.php');
$db_link=mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbuser, $dbpassword,$dbname) or die("Unable to connect to the server!");
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','../font/');
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(25,7,"answerid");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"email");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"qst");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"answer");
$pdf->Ln();
include ('db.php');
$db_link=mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbuser, $dbpassword,$dbname) or die("Unable to connect to the server!");

        $sql = "SELECT answerid,email,qst,answer FROM responses where email='".$_SESSION['usr_id']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_link,$sql);

        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $rows['answerid'];
            $email = $rows['email'];
            $question = $rows['qst'];
            $answer = $rows['answer'];
            $pdf->Cell(25,7,$id);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$email);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$question);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$answer);
        }
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Well, it's a strange thing to get off from, but each to our own. - None the less, your question isn't really suited for SO.

Comment: SO is a Q/A site, not a free coding service. Here we help you to **fix existing** code, but will not write code for you from scratch.

Comment: i dont want you to write code for me. i want some suggetion that how can i done this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tcpdf](https://tcpdf.org/) library for convert html into pdf file. You can generate pdf file and you can send it to user using [php_mailer](http://github.com/anshkatriya/php_mailer) library. (Add generated pdf file as attachment.)

Comment: where can i download this tcpdf library